# code for generated numbers and how to show highest number to low

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Need a program that generates 10 numbers from 1 to 6. code must be stored in an integer array and find out the highest, minimum value of the numbers generated and displayed in the code, also the overall summ of all the numbers generated from 1-6. All three functions must be returned in main..

ok! im awake now i can see that i can edite my original post so here goes my almost finished code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
int highest = INT_MAX;
int lowest = INT_MIN;
int i = 0;
int sum = 0;

{
 {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        cout << rand() % 6 + 1 << endl;

 }
int myArray[10]{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };  

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

    myArray[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;  

    if (myArray[i] < lowest)
        lowest = myArray[i];

    if (myArray[i] > highest)
        highest = myArray[i];

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

        sum = sum + rand() % 6 + 1;

        cout << "The sum of all 10 numbers is " << sum << endl;
        cout << "The largest value is = " << INT_MAX << endl;
        cout << "The smallest value is = " << INT_MIN << endl;

    }
    return 1;
    }
  }
```

My problem here is that i cant define the int_max or int_min to display my highest numbers from 1-6 . i have tried other examples with int_m but it doesntn work. im hoping some u can give me a hint what im doing worng. Thank you

Comment: SO is not a coding service. So, you may ask for a hint "How to do it?" or better a bug fix but not as you did: Please, complete this so that I can learn how to do it. (Or did I misunderstand you?) However, you have to add local variables which store the intermediate (or final) results before they are used for output. Thus, they can be processed before or afterwards.

Comment: ofc ! i meant asing for a hint how to do it or how i should proceed. i understand now about the local variables that store the results before they are used for output.

Comment: So, don't worry about the down-votes because you got two answers which explain any missing aspect (and even more). I would count this as success. It would be kind to _accept_ the answer which helped you most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, be careful with the indentation of your code.

Next, you need to keep track of every generated number by declaring an array.

```
srand(time(0));

//You have to include the limits library to use INT_MIN and INT_MAX
int highest = INT_MIN;
int lowest = INT_MAX;

int myArray[10];   //Array to hold 10 random numbers

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
{
    myArr[i] = rand() % 6 + 1;  // Generates a random number and stores it 

    if (myArr[i] < lowest)
         lowest = myArr[i];
    else if (myArr[i] > highest)
         highest = myArr[i];
}
```

Now highest variable should hold the higest number generated and lowest variable should hold the lowest generated number.

And please next time please do more research before asking and be more specific.

Comment: ty im still figuring it out but its more clearer now. (im starting to see the light out of this) :)

Comment: well i give up for the night.. im almost there but i cant solve the highest number and lowest number from my 10 generated numbers that go from 1-6... help plz have been studying this problem the whole damn weeken. altough i have learned alot. yes im a newbie

Comment: i had to use this so i can show my ongoing code...its 4 AM i didnt know how to properly insert the code in comments. sorry

http://freetexthost.com/26syhvjljv


@francis Cugler ty again for the help i just need the final push. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to use `rand()` or `srand()` there is a safer, more efficient and reliable way to generate random numbers. I will be showing you how to use one of many random number generators that are defined in the standard library. I will be using a `random device` to seed the `engine` or `generator` and the generator I will be using is the standard `mersenne_twister_engine` shown as `mt19937`. I will be using a `uniform_int_distribution` for the distribution type. There are many other types of generators that can be used, other types of distributions and a few other ways to seed these engines; another way to seed these besides a `random_device` is by using `std::chrono` time or steady clock system. You can find out more about these pseudo random number generators and distributions found here: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) to use these you will need to include the header file `<random>`.

I will be using a `std::vector` to contain the numbers generated and for this you will need to include `<vector>` although if you are required to use a basic default array you can easily replace the vector with an array of ints. I choose to use the `std::vector<int>` because of the already existing algorithms in the standard library that are available to you to perform the needed or required operations that you are asking for such as finding the minimum and maximum values and by adding all of the elements in that sequence or range of values. To use these algorithms you will need to include `<algorithm>` and `<numeric>`.

Here is the short program that I wrote strictly in the main function to show all the functionality that you are asking for. If you need to have these in separate functions that are called within the main then I leave that as a task for you to accomplish.

```
#include <iostream>   // Output
#include <vector>     // Container
#include <algorithm>  // Algorithms
#include <numeric>    // Other Needed Functions

int main() {

    std::random_device rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
    std::mt19937 gen( rd() ); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis( 1, 6 ); // Distribution Of Random Numbers in range of [1,6]

    // Vector Or Array To Store Numbers
    std::vector<int> numbers;

    // Populate Vector
    int n = 0;
    for ( ; n < 10; ++n){
        numbers.push_back( dis( gen ) );
    }

    // Display Random Values
    n = 0;
    for ( ; n < 10; ++n ) {
        std::cout << numbers[n] << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Min & Max
    std::vector<int>::iterator resultMin;
    std::vector<int>::iterator resultMax;

    resultMin = std::min_element(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
    resultMax = std::max_element(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));

    // Sum
    int sum = std::accumulate(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), 0);

    // Display Results
    std::cout << "min value is: " << (*resultMin) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "max value is: " << (*resultMax) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sum of array is: " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is `std::minmax_element` to do `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` with little less comparisons.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure; but I was showing the OP that there does already exist algorithms to suite their needs. I wasn't overly concerned about efficiency just by how the OP had asked the question. They first need to learn the language syntax and concepts, then the libraries, then worry about refining code to make it more efficient.

Comment: TY i was considering going this way but im choosing a more simple aproach. good to have different options and i i see how i can experiment more watching ur code. ty again

Comment: @coto well the way you think that is simpler is actually a little harder because you will never get a true random number with `rand()` or `srand()` The distribution of their outputs through loops is not all that random... in fact they are predictable for each independent seed value. However with using the standard library's methods you will get randomly generated numbers using the same seed random_device or chrono::clock. Vectors contain easily and have fast indexing. They are linear search and methods already to find min, max, and accumulate are already implemented; not much easier than this.

Comment: I see... Because im still struggling with my problem to be solve, im gonna check this approach more. Its just that i havent Come to this sektion in my book about using The std random devise and The other two u mention.  Felt like more outside of The things im learning because i havent encountered it in the book.  But as i feel that my book isnt teaching me as good as The internet is, this may help me also.

Comment: http://freetexthost.com/nxrlh3r3oo


almost finished with my code i just need help with the highest and lowest not showing from the 1-6 range as i like to.... ty in advance!